# Not getting proper output using 'from file' and 'to file' blocks in simulink (matlab)

Tags: simulink

%% my code as per the mathwork document:
%%% used time series format in 'from file' and 'to file' blocks.

```
t = (0:10);
d= [1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1];
x = [t;d];
ts = timeseries(x(2:end,:),x(1,:));
save('mysignal','ts','-v7.3');
```

I run the simulink as per the image attached[load and get the matfile back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAwp2.png)

simulink runs without error but I am not getting the same data inside the output file data_op_mat.mat

When I load data_op_mat.mat it gives the following

```
K>> load('data_op_mat.mat')
K>> ans
  timeseries

  Common Properties:
            Name: ''
            Time: [51x1 double]
        TimeInfo: [1x1 tsdata.timemetadata]
            Data: [51x1 double]
        DataInfo: [1x1 tsdata.datametadata]
```

Answer (score 0):

The time vector in the input data is used purely to define what the input signal looks like, it has no effect on how the Simulink solver works - most notably for you, it has no effect on the time steps that the Simulink model takes.

Your output time vector has 51 elements.
This indicates that you are running the model using the default start time (0s), the default stop time (10s), using the default solver (variable step, ode45), and the default maximum step size for the solver (auto).
auto means take a maximum step size of (stop time - start time)/50 = 0.2.

There's nothing in your model preventing the solver taking the largest time steps it can, so every time step is 0.2s.
So from 0 to 10, at a step size of 0.2, will give 51 time steps, which is what you have.

I suspect tat if you plot the output series you'll see that it is just an interpolation of the input data at those time points.

Comment: Thanks very much. Could I know exactly what to do, to get the output same as the input with size (1*11). Could you please elaborate. @Phil Goddard?

Comment: The easiest thing to do in this specific case is open the `To Workspace` block and change the sample time to `1`.  But that's most likely not what you'll want to do with a larger/more complex model.

Comment: As you said I am able to do this with "from workspace" block and "to workspace" block. But .mat file is more convenient for me.That why I am trying from  "From file". There should be some method. And for any size input I am always getting output vector as 51 elements.

Comment: My comment should have said to set the sample time of the `From File` block.  You are getting 51 steps because of the way the solver works for this very simple model.  It has nothing to do with the time points you use in the input file data.